# Connecting a wordpress site to an AngularJS APP

Tags: javascript, json, oauth, rest-api

Currently I have a application that needs a blogging system added. The application is built with an AngularJS front-end and a python/Django back end.  I wanted to use wordpress as the blogging system as the end client is very familiar with it.  I am looking for the most effective way to pull from wordpress into angularJS.  Most tutorials I have found to this point are for creating an Angular Theme which isn't exactly what I am looking to do.  Any info to point me in the correct direction would be excellent.

Comment: I would say, your best shot is the WP API - search the site (and the net), there is already some information available. Otherwise this is a bit too broad to be answerable - according to the guideline -, so I close voted because of broadness - just for your information.

Comment: http://v2.wp-api.org -> http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/418/angular-wordpress-seed-a-complete-example-project-with-angularjs-and-the-wordpress-json-rest-api

Comment: @ialocin Thank you.  Was already looking at WP API and found some intro tutorials and articles but nothing that went into depth on pulling advanced content (menus, custom post types, custom fields, etc..).  Will continue to search.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WP API to pull in content, posts, pages. I don't think that menus are in the API and I found that I wanted my own menu structure for my WP/angular apps anyway.